# Helm chart kubernetes-dashboard. Cannot upgrade to version 5.0.0

Tags: kubernetes-dashboard, helm3

Im trying to upgrade kubernetes-dashboard helm chart to version 5.0.0
When i run helm sync it gives me error

```
Error: chart requires kubeVersion: >=1.19.0-0 which is incompatible with Kubernetes v1.18.0
```

My kubernetes versions are

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.2", GitCommit:"faecb196815e248d3ecfb03c680a4507229c2a56", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-14T05:14:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.3", GitCommit:"ca643a4d1f7bfe34773c74f79527be4afd95bf39", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-07-15T20:59:07Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}



helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.3.4", GitCommit:"a61ce5633af99708171414353ed49547cf05013d", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.14.9"}
```

why it thinks that my kubernetes version is 1.18.0

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with version of Helm.
After ive installed v3.7.0 it all works ok.

Comment: after upgrading from 3.4.0 -> 3.8.0, this error is gone